# youtube bounding box dataset: images

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

Does anyone know a source for the [google bounding box dataset](https://research.google.com/youtube-bb/) image files? The annotations are available on the site along with the relevant details to find the youtube videos and extract the appropriate frames, but I'm not too keen to download 240k videos...

Comment: What exactly *do* you want?

Comment: A compact source of the image files.

Comment: A video is very often more compact than individual frames compressed separately.

Comment: I don't want all the frames. I want 15-20 per video segment. The segments might be a minute or longer at ~30 fps. Video compression may be good, but I doubt it's -that- good for natural videos. I wouldn't mind if it was a couple of hundred videos, but we're talking 240 000.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯